# How do you take first three letters of two strings in VB 2010 Console App to make a Username of some sort?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, console

How do you take first three letters of two strings in VB 2010 Console App to make a Username of some sort?

For example

```
Dim FName As String
Dim SName As String
Dim Username As String

FName = Jonhson
SName = Robertson
```

Outcome:

```
Username = JonRob
```

Comment: Username = FName.SubString(0,3) & SName.SubString(0,3)

Comment: Don't forget that names don't have to be 3 letters long. Also a good read: http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to take 3 characters from each string and concat both to the `UserName`?

One way `Substring`:

```
Username = FName.Substring(0, If(FName.Length >= 3, 3, FName.Length)) &
           SName.Substring(0, If(SName.Length >= 3, 3, SName.Length))
```

Another, `Take` + `Concat` + `Join`:

```
Username = String.Join("", FName.Take(3).Concat(SName.Take(3)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use substring

```
Username = FName.Substring(0, 3) + SName.Substring(0, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Username = String.Format("{0}{1}", FName.SubString(0,3), SName.SubString(0,3))
```

Comment: In the future, it is helpful if you explain how you arrived at this, and how it works. Thanks!